# Javascript - split string and output results on separate lines

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

What I'm trying to do is take a comma separated string like "HTML5,CSS3,Compass,JavaScript,jQuery,PHP,Foundation,Drupal,WordPress" - split that string into and array and write a loop that outputs each array item on a separate line.

This works:

```
function splitstr() {
 var splitStr = "HTML5,CSS3,Compass,JavaScript,jQuery,PHP,Foundation,Drupal,WordPress";
 var output = splitStr.split(',');
 for (var i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
   document.write(output[i] + "<br />");
 }
}
```

but obviously it outputs to a blank page. I need it to output the results into a div.

So I try the following code but it doesn't work. It only prints out the last one "Wordpress".

```
function splitstr() {
 var splitStr = "HTML5,CSS3,Compass,JavaScript,jQuery,PHP,Foundation,Drupal,WordPress";
 var output = splitStr.split(",");
 for (var i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById("splitres").innerHTML = output[i] + "<br />";
 }
}
```

what am i doing wrong?

agon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 document.getElementById("splitres").innerHTML += output[i] + "<br />";
```

Note `+`. With that, you are appending HTML; without it, you are overwriting it.

Comment: Nice & concise explanation! +

Comment: @agon024, please accept the answer if it's the correct one.